# Show a decimal number using a superscripted scientific number

Tags: formula

A client asked me (using an example):

> If a value in a Salesforce field is `567123.44`, how can I show it to
>   look like `5.6712344x10⁵`
>
> The superscripted exponent is very important for the users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to go back to high school math.  What you want to assemble in a formula field is

```
mantissa x 10 <some superscripted exponent>
```

- Let's assume the base value is in a custom field `Measurement__c`
- We know that `FLOOR(LOG(Measurement__c))` is the necessary exponent. For example: `LOG(567123.44) = 5.75367759765`. We're interested in the integer part of this fraction and `FLOOR` gets us that.
- We also know there are [UTF-8 characters for superscripted 0-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts_(Unicode_block)).
- We have to handle negative exponents; e.g. `LOG(.001) = -3`
- We have to handle null and zero (`LOG(0) is undefined`).
- SFDC Decimal fields can be defined with 18 significant digits.

So, putting this altogether into a new formula field (1,344 compiled characters) `Measurement_Friendly__c` we have:

```
/* 
  Generates n.nnnn x10<superscriptedExponent> e.g. 8.923x10¹ 
  Notes: 
  1. Exponent == FLOOR(LOG(Measurement__c)) - used in five places */

IF(Measurement__c = 0,'0.00',  /* special case for zero */
   Text(Measurement__c / (10 ^ FLOOR(LOG(Measurement__c)))) &   /* Mantissa */

   'x10' & 

   IF(FLOOR(LOG(Measurement__c)) < 0,'⁻',NULL) &  /* negative exponent if needed */
   Case(ABS(FLOOR(LOG(Measurement__c))),  /* derive superscripted exponent  */
     0,'⁰',
     1,'¹',
     2,'² ',
     3,'³',
     4,'⁴',
     5,'⁵',
     6,'⁶',
     7,'⁷',
     8,'⁸',
     9,'⁹',
     /* in case exponent is > ABS(9) */ 
     'E' & IF(FLOOR(LOG(Measurement__c)) < 0,'-',NULL) & TEXT(FLOOR(LOG(Measurement__c)))
 ))
```

*The above formula assumes the input range for `Measurement__c is between n x10⁹ and n x 10⁻⁹`.  You can adjust the CASE statement to go beyond that range (e.g. 10¹⁰ or more).*

[image]